# iPad Utility Application - where is MainView.xib loaded?

Tags: ipad

I've created a Utility application targeted at the **iPad** using the boilerplate code and I can quite happily load a new version of the FlipsideView.xib by changing the line

FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView~iPad" bundle:nil];

In MainViewController.m, where FlipsideView~iPad.xib is a newly created copy of the original file.

However I cannot see where MainView.xib itself is loaded.  I can change the MainWindow.xib to MainWindow~iPad.xib in the plist, and the FlibsideView.xib using the above in MainViewController.m, but I cannot see where MainView.xib is loaded.  Where is that?  Certainly I can just edit MainView.xib itself, but not understanding how this is loaded seems dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is loaded by the `UIApplicationMain` function, which is called from `main` in the `main.m` file. The only way to change the name of the nib that is loaded is to change the `NSMainNibFile` key in your `Info.plist` file. See the [UIApplicationMain reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain) for more information.